# Looking for Spatio-temporal Datasets

Tags: data-request, geospatial

A spatio-temporal dataset is a dataset which contains latitude/longitude and also time variables.

I got a spatio-temporal dataset on [this site](http://js.cit.datalens.api.here.com/datasets/starter_pack/Earthquakes_7day.csv). The dataset contains 1077 rows of data. The problem is, the size of the dataset is too small.

If anyone has another link to a spatio-temporal dataset with big size and CSV format and also free, please help.

Comment: There's tons of weather data around. Are you looking for specific space/time data?

Comment: Hello sir, the important variable is date/time and latitude-longitude. It will be better if the data is disaster data

Comment: https://www.emsc-csem.org/Earthquake/world/ contains global earthquake data if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this thread: [Where can I find free spatio-temporal dataset for download?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/997/where-can-i-find-free-spatio-temporal-dataset-for-download)

there is a dataset around NYC's taxi trip data: http://www.andresmh.com/nyctaxitrips/. Variables include time and location for both pickups and drop-offs.
Or: You can get yellow and green taxi trip records from NYC taxi dataset. The website collects data from 2009 until now: http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml

Another dataset comes from Chicago's bike-sharing service: https://www.divvybikes.com/datachallenge.

You can also get some documented, publicly available EEG data from the HeadIT database at UCSD http://headit-beta.ucsd.edu/studies

I'm sure there are many more options.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:
https://github.com/Call-for-Code/logistics-weather-geo/wiki/DataResources

I have a section called "Hazards" which lists many disaster-related sources of open data.

Answer (score 1):

Not disaster-specific, but Microsoft Urban Computing has a lot of different options (see "Released Datasets"):
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/urban-computing/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [NASA's worldview](https://worldview.earthdata.nasa.gov/) and the underlying [NASA Global Imagery Browse Services (GIBS)](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/about/science-system-description/eosdis-components/global-imagery-browse-services-gibs)
explain how to use their APIs to download lots and lots of spatial data.

The Worldview app gives you a powerful slider control to view satellite images over time, interactively, in your browser.

About *Worldview*:

> This app from NASA's EOSDIS provides the capability to interactively
>   browse over 800 global, full-resolution satellite imagery layers and
>   then download the underlying data.

GIBS APIs: https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/GIBS/GIBS+API+for+Developers